# MVC Url Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to generate URL like.. It should include two IDs with employer and job including.
I am confused and have no idea about it. I have a controller `Employer`.

```
http://localhost/Employer/[employerID]/job/[jobid]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EmplyerJob", // Route name
    "Employer/{empid}/job/{jobid}",
    new { controller = "Employer",
          action = "Job" }
);
```

I have made a few changes to Xander's answer.  I don't think you'll want to use parameters here, as this will throw off other routes to other controllers/action methods.  If you use the hard-coded `"Employer"` and `"job"` strings, you will be narrowing down what routes are analyzed by this route.

Also, you can't have an optional parameter before a required parameter.